# Is there any easy, documented or official way to replace pullback mechanism with Motor Set 8293

Tags: technic, power-functions

There are many Technic cars with a pullback mechanism, like 42059, 42073 or 42072.

Is there any systematic, easy, documented or official way to replace the pullback mechanism with the LEGO Technic Power Functions Motor Set 8293?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I dont't see how a standard way could exist. That would pretty much require a setup with a PF motor, gears, etc. having the same size and interface as the pullback 
motor, which according to bricklink (I don't think I have any) is 6x5x3. As far as I remember the only PF motor shorter than 6 studs (there has to be room for at least one gear) is the XL, but that's 5 studs wide.

For any given set, it's quite possible that you could find a solution, and even that the same solution would work for a lot of sets.

Answer (score 3):

It isn't clear what do you mean by "replace with 8293 set". Just with a motor? While there isn't official way (instructions) of doing it I think it is possible to fit the M-motor included in 8293 set with few additional parts. However then there is a question of power. You need to attach battery box somehow. I see this as a bigger issue as there is no convenient place to attach it to.